# Bootstrap dropdown change icon class on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the Bootstrap framework dropdown as a sort of select. See image bellow:

[image]

When the user clicks on each of the dropdown links, a js function is fired to set a cookie defining the user's city/region. `-> This is working!`

The same function adds a class to the icon of the clicked link within the dropdown to indicate the selected item/city (see the "green dot icon" in the image above). `-> This works as soon as the link is clicked!`

BUT

The function fails to keep the icon new css class after the page reloads, and I have no active item at all, only two grey dots.  `-> Fail!`

Here's the html:

```
<a href="#" id="city_1'" class="define-city-1" data-city="city1" role="menuitem">
<i class="icon large-point grey-300" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    Betim
</a>


function reload_city() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        // redirect to the current url + the query string built with the cookie value
        window.location = window.location.pathname + '?city=' + jQuery.cookie('city');
    }, 1000);
}

jQuery("#city_1").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery.cookie('city', jQuery(this).attr('data-city'));

    if(jQuery(this).attr('data-city') == jQuery.cookie('city')){
        jQuery(this).children('i').removeClass('grey-300');
        jQuery(this).children('i').addClass('green-600'); 
    }

    reload_city();
    e.stopPropagation();

});
```

I was wondering what causes this behavior on reload, and I'd really appreciate any inputs regarding this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you checking on page load if the cookie is already set?

Comment: No. The only check I do is with php in WordPress so I can display different content depending on the cookie value that is set "on click" with the js function above. However, I can't see the point of checking the cookie on page refresh? Would that help to keep the class set after the page is reloaded?

Comment: I've tried to pass the check to the page refresh function and that seems not to work...

Comment: @LakenH. Thanks for the suggestion about checking if the cookie is already set. I've rewritten the fucntion to make a simple check for the cookie on `document.ready` .